# function that takes two parameters of string type which are fractions with the same denominator and returns a sum expression and the sum result

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, integer, fractions

For example:

```
>>> a_b = '1/3'
>>> c_b = '5/3'
>>> get_fractions(a_b, c_b)
'1/3 + 5/3 = 6/3'`
```

I'm trying to solve this but it won't work:

```
def get_fractions(a_b: str, c_b: str) -> str:
    calculate = int(a_b) + int(c_b)
    return calculate
```

Answer (score 1):

First you will have to get the nominator and denominator for each argument. After that you convert the nominator of each argument from string to integer and add them. Then lastly convert the sum of nominators to str and concatenate it with '/' and any of the argument denominator.

```py
def get_fractions(a_b: str, c_b: str) -> str:
    a_b = a_b.split('/')
    a_n, a_d = a_b[0], a_b[1]
    c_b = c_b.split('/')
    c_n, c_d = c_b[0], c_b[1]
    n_sum = int(c_n) + int(a_n)
    out = f'{n_sum} / {a_d}'
    return out
```

**Output**

```
6 / 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_fractions(a_b, c_b):
    sum_of=int(a_b[0])+int(c_b[0])
    text = f"{a_b} + {c_b} = {sum_of}/{a_b[2]}"
    print(text)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_fractions(a_b: str, c_b: str) -> str:
    a = a_b.split('/')
    b = c_b.split('/')

    return f'{a_b} + {c_b} = {int(a[0]) + int(b[0])}/{b[1]}'
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide a textual explanation about your solution.

Comment: @Itération122442: Good call. This is a reason to downvote, though, not to vote to delete.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34641445)